# How to Change Specific Widgets in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, width

I want to ask about how to change widget width size in WordPress.

I've tried it myself but no results, I've tried searching through the inspect element but I can't find its code in the template editor, and also I've tried to do with custom CSS but no changes to widget width size.

Is there any other solution to overcome this?

Thanks.

- I just want to change the width size on 1 widget

Comment: in your theme you will mentioned the count and and looping process of the footer widget, there you can add custom Id for each and apply the size manually.

Comment: Every widget usually comes with it's own unique `id` attribute you can use as a css selector to declare custom styles. What have you been trying?

Comment: you should add relevant html and applied css for your element, depending on your theme, a widget can be sized by different ways (css rules, class, bootstrap, etc), we can't help you without this

Answer (score 0):

Click to this tool.

[image]

After it gets blue color, click to that widget and you will get highlighted HTML code of that widget, and from there you will easily find its ID and CSS class name.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Add Custom Styles to WordPress Widgets](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-wordpress-widgets/)

[How to Customize a Specific WordPress Widget](http://wpfab.com/how-to-customize-a-specific-wordpress-widget/)

[Need Custom class Then add plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/)